# How to access variable outside the function scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote simple javascript class to use AudioRecorder feature of browser
I have variable mediaRecorder  inside initAudio scope, I want to access it
inside another function startRecording

How can i do it ?

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia );
var audioCtx = new ( window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext )();
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
var scriptProcessor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor( 2048, 1, 1 );
var chunks = [ ], input = null;
var mediaRecorder;
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
analyser.fftSize = 1024;

var AudioRecorder = function( element ) {

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
    navigator.getUserMedia( { audio: true }, function( stream ) {
        initAudio( stream );
    }, function( err ) {
        console.log( 'usermedia error', err );
    } );

    var initAudio = function( stream ) {
        input = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource( stream );
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder( stream );

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function( e ) {
            chunks.push( e.data );
        };

        mediaRecorder.onstop = function( e ) {
            console.log( "data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called." );
            var blob = new Blob( chunks, { 'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' } );
            chunks = [ ];

            var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob );
            document.getElementById( 'blo' ).href = audioURL;
            console.log( audioURL );
        };

    };

    this.startRecording = function() {
        console.log( mediaRecorder );
        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log( mediaRecorder.state );
        console.log( "recorder started" );
        this.isRecording = true;
    };

    this.stopRecording = function() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        console.log( mediaRecorder.state );
        console.log( "recorder stopped" );
    };

};

var element = document.getElementById( 'mediaPlayer' );
var record = new AudioRecorder( element );
record.startRecording();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I'm facing problem in special case with audio recording @AmericanSlime

Comment: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/4-javascript-design-patterns-you-should-know

Comment: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: You can make errors no matter what style of coding you use. Your code style looks ok, but after quick look I can't help but notice that you declare your `mediaRecorder` variable inside one function, while trying to use it later inside another function, that is outside of it's scope. You might want to fix some bugs and stay with the class you have. ... although, there is nothing wrong with learning new things ;)

Comment: I rewrote my question, please try to answer @i--

Comment: @SurjitSidhu, not a good idea to change question drastically after it being open for a while. You seem to fix the issue I was talking about by reassigning the variable at the top instead of inside the `initAudio` function, but might be a better place right above the `initAudio` function inside the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your code and this seem ok.

The trouble is not an scope variable issue. I thinks that your init() function does not be executed because does not exists a stream flowing to web page.

I made a couple of modifications to demostrate this.

```
var audioCtx = new ( window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext )();
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
var scriptProcessor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor( 2048, 1, 1 );
var chunks = [ ], input = null;
var mediaRecorder = null;
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
analyser.fftSize = 1024;

var AudioRecorder = function( element ) {

/***navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
        navigator.getUserMedia( { audio: true }, function( stream ) {
            initAudio( stream );
        }, function( err ) {
            console.log( 'usermedia error', err );
        } );***/
        // First get User Media
        var md = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
        md.then(function(mediaStream) {
            console.log('Media function');
            this.initAudio( stream );
        });
        md.catch(function(err) { console.log('usermedia error', err); }); // always check for errors at the end

        var initAudio = function( stream ) {
            input = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource( stream );
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder( stream );

            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function( e ) {
                chunks.push( e.data );
            };

            mediaRecorder.onstop = function( e ) {
                console.log( "data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called." );
                var blob = new Blob( chunks, { 'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' } );
                chunks = [ ];

                var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob );
                document.getElementById( 'blo' ).href = audioURL;
                console.log( audioURL );
            };

        };

        this.startRecording = function() {
            console.log( mediaRecorder );
            mediaRecorder.start();
            console.log( mediaRecorder.state );
            console.log( "recorder started" );
            this.isRecording = true;
        };

        this.stopRecording = function() {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            console.log( mediaRecorder.state );
            console.log( "recorder stopped" );
        };

    };

    var element = document.getElementById( 'mediaPlayer' );
    var record = new AudioRecorder( element );
    record.startRecording();
```

This references can be useful to you:

[Mozilla Media Devices Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

[How to recording videos in the browser](https://60devs.com/recording-videos-in-the-browser-using-media-recorder-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
function foo() {
  ...
  return {
    startRecording: function() { ... },
    stopRecording: function() { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: I rewrote my question, please try to answer